# Is it a good idea to close the JDBC connection in case of PG Listen/Notify polling?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, hikaricp

We use connection pool in our application. While I understand that we should close and get connections as needed since we are using a connection pool. I implemented a cache update mechanism by receiving Postgres `LISTEN` notifications. The code is pretty much similar to the canonical example given by the [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/listennotify.html).

As you can see in the code, the query is initiated in the constructor and the connection is re used. This may pose problem when the connection is closed out of band due to any factor. One solution to this is to get the connection before every use, but as you can see the statement is only executed once in the constructor but still I can receive the notification in the polling. So if I get the connection every time, it will force me to re issue the statement for every iteration(after delay). I'm not sure if that's an expensive operation.

What is the middle ground here?

```
class Listener extends Thread
{
private Connection conn;
private org.postgresql.PGConnection pgconn;

Listener(Connection conn) throws SQLException
{
    this.conn = conn;
    this.pgconn = conn.unwrap(org.postgresql.PGConnection.class);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute("LISTEN mymessage");
    stmt.close();
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            org.postgresql.PGNotification notifications[] = pgconn.getNotifications();

          
            if (notifications != null)
            {
                for (int i=0; i < notifications.length; i++){
                    //use notification
                }   
            }

            Thread.sleep(delay);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        //handle
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ie)
    {
        //handle
    }
}
```

}

In addition to this, there is also another similar [document](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/listennotify.html) which had another query in run method as well in addition to constructor. I'm wondering if someone could enlighten me the purpose of another query within the method.

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            //this query is additional to the one in the constructor
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 1");
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();

            org.postgresql.PGNotification notifications[] = pgconn.getNotifications();
            if (notifications != null) {
                for (int i=0; i<notifications.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Got notification: " + notifications[i].getName());
                }
            }

            // wait a while before checking again for new
            // notifications
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            //handle
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            //handle
        }
    }
}
```

I experimented closing the connection in every iteration(but without getting another one). That's still working. Perhaps that's due to unwrap that was done.

Stack:
Spring Boot, JPA, Hikari, Postgres JDBC Driver (not pgjdbc-ng)

Comment: Who ever added close vote, I request them to add a comment here so that I will know and improve the question. I posted this as a last resort. This is not an open ended question.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question. I don't have any solution for this. Someone should answer to even make it clear that if it's opinion based or not. That is if someone clearly knows if there are alternatives and they are equivalent. At this point I'm not even sure how to keep the connection alive in this situation.

Comment: Closing the connection on every iteration and *not* re-acquiring it sure doesn't work for me: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed`.  It also doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jjanes I meant pgjdbc-ng. I edited question now.

Comment: @jjanes Yeah, that was just an experiment to see if I get that error, but I didn't for some reason. I did get this error without closing as well though when the application is left running for sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection pool is the servant, not the master. Keep the connection for as long as you are using it to LISTEN on, i.e. ideally forever.  If the connection ever does close, then you will miss whatever notices were sent while it was closed. So to keep the cache in good shape, you would need to discard the whole thing and start over.  Obviously not something you would want to do on a regular basis, or what would be the point of having it in the first place?

The other doc you show is just an ancient version of the first one.  The dummy query just before polling is there to poke the underlying socket code to make sure it has absorbed all the messages.  This is no longer necessary.  I don't know if it ever was necessary, it might have just been some cargo cult that found its way into the docs.

You would probably be better off with the blocking version of this code, by using `getNotifications(0)` and getting rid of `sleep(delay)`.  This will block until a notice becomes available, rather than waking up twice a second and consuming some (small) amount of resources before sleeping again.  Also, once a notice does arrive it will be processed almost immediately, instead of waiting for what is left of a half-second timeout to expire (so, on average, about a quarter second).

Comment: Thanks. I actually implemented a re initiation method that checks if connection is closed and starts over the process before getting notification to avoid "This connection has been closed" error when I left the application up for long time. So I guess that's the way to keep the connection up but also not re issue the query every time.

Comment: Number of records in my cache are limited(100-500ish). But the likelyhood of table update is less as well. So I actually reload the cache on any update notification. The trouble I was having is to keep the connection alive to avoid "The connection has been closed". The answers elsewhere suggest getting connection every time and close it but my situation is different as it's about PG Listen.